# WP7 Binding in App.xaml Application.Resources

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, resources

In App.xaml  `<Application.Resources>`

I have:

```
<Color x:Key="ColorMain">#FF1F879C</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorBrushMain" Color="{StaticResource ColorMain}"/>
```

then I have many templates which are using this brush and color. These templates are used all over the application.

I need to have an ability to change the color to change the skin of whole application.
I need something like:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorBrushMain" Color="{Binding ColorMain}"/>
```

and in code something like:

```
 public string ColorMain {
    get {
       return ..... ; // "#FF803200";
    }
 }
```

But it doesn't work. Please help.

UPD: abhinav is right it must be a color

```
 public Color ColorMain {
    get {
       return ..... ; // return Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x80, 0x32, 0x00);
    }
 }
```

but this is not enough, it's not binding. I assume that it must be something as on normal page with `DataContext` to `ViewModel`,  but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're binding to a property that stores the Color and you're going to change at runtime and expect it to update, don't you need to be implementing INotifyPropertyChanged as well? For example:

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged

    private Color _mainColor
    public Color MainColor
    {
        get { return _mainColor; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _mainColor)
            {
                _mainColor= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MainColor");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

So: if you're expecting to change the color at runtime, use binding and implement INotifyPropertyChanged - if the colour isn't going to change at runtime, what you've already got should be fine.

Comment: That's right. That's how I would do on normal page which is PhoneApplicationPage and you can place this.DataContext=MyViewModel, but I am asking how should I do it from App.xaml which is Application and doesn't have DataContext field.

Comment: It's not about the DataContext, but about the DependencyProperty / notifying property changes, so you should be able to wrap a property in App.xaml.cs to do the same thing. This link also may or may not help - http://forums.silverlight.net/t/229874.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

You're binding a color property to a string object. 
Although I've never tried it, I'm quite sure that it will not work.

Maybe the documentation of the class will help. [See this link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx)

Did you try using the color class instead?

```
    public Color ColorMain {
    get {
       return ..... ; // "#FF803200";
    }
 }
```

Comment: use the Color FromArgb method to convert your hex value into color object. [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833.aspx).

Comment: Why don't you add the resource directly form code? `Resources.Add("ColorMain", Color.FromARGB(a, r, g, b));` All controls that use this resource will be updated from the next page you navigate.